# UnsatisfiedLinkError ClassName.methodName()V

Tags: java, linker, java-native-interface

I am making a simple program to test using JNI for calling C code in a Java program (on Windows machine) but I am getting an UnsatisfiedLinkError.

The error:

```
$ ls
HelloWorld.class  HelloWorld.h  HelloWorld.java  ctest.c  ctest.dll

$ java HelloWorld
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: HelloWorld.helloFromC()V
    at HelloWorld.helloFromC(Native Method)
    at HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:9)
```

HelloWorld.java

```
public class HelloWorld {
    native void helloFromC();
    static {
            System.loadLibrary("ctest");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            HelloWorld helloWorld = new HelloWorld();
            helloWorld.helloFromC();
    }
}
```

ctest.c

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_HelloWorld_helloFromC (JNIEnv * env, jobject jobj) {
        printf("Hello from C!\n");
}
```

I generated the header file `HelloWorld.h` with no problems, compiled so I have `HelloWorld.class`, and created my native library `ctest.dll` but when I try to run it, it throws the error mentioned above. I've tried to user the absolute path when loading my library and explicitly including the header file in my native code in `ctest.c`. I've also tried just using `System.load()` with the fully qualified path and still produce the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened to me when using MinGW to compile on a Windows 7 machine. And it was fixed when I found in this document http://www.academia.edu/5449209/JNI that to successfully link JNI you need to add a the parameter -Wl,--add-stdcall-alias.
Like this:
gcc -Wl,--add-stdcall-alias -I"\include" -I"\include\win32" -shared -o hello.dll HelloJNI.c
This will make an alias of the symbol without some @nn suffixes that MinGW adds to the DLL and this way java will recognize the method.